# How to add new data in existing state in react native?

Tags: state, react-native, react-native-listview

I am trying to implement pagination. I am fetching array of 10 items in every `fetch request` and saving them in state when `onEndReached` of listview will called I am fetching next items and so on.

My problem is when I am fetching next array of items, the items from previous fetch which are saved in state they are vanishing. and as I updating the state only currently fetched items are displaying.

I want that items from previous fetch should not vanishes on next fetch. Can I append the new items to the existing state? If yes how can I do it?

If I am going wrong then how can I achieve this using any component of react native which is I am unaware of?

Here is my code

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        next: "",
        qwerty: []
    };
    this.fetchData = this.fetchData.bind(this);
}

fetchData() {
    return fetch('https://shopconapp.herokuapp.com/api/pagination/')

        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseData) => {
            if (!responseData) {
                navigate("Login");
            } else {
                console.log(responseData);

                let ds = new ListView.DataSource({ rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2 });
                this.setState({
                    nexturl: responseData.next,
                    qwerty: ds.cloneWithRows(responseData.results.post),
                });
            }
        })
}

_onEndReached(){

    url = this.state.nexturl;

    return fetch(this.state.nexturl)

        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseData) => {
            if (!responseData) {
                navigate("Login");
            } else {
                console.log(responseData);

                let ds = new ListView.DataSource({ rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2 });
                this.setState({
                    nexturl: responseData.next,
                    qwerty: ds.cloneWithRows(responseData.results.post),
                });

            }
        })
}

<ListView
    dataSource={this.state.qwerty}
    onEndReachedThreshold={2}
    onEndReached={this._onEndReached.bind(this)}
/>
```

Comment: yes, you can update the state, show the code you are trying as so far.

Comment: So basically you need your items to be saved and not overwritten. For that you can cache your existing state inside some sort of base state, and then append the new items into the base state.

Comment: Yes, you can add data to the previous one by just adding or appending the fetched value to the previous one.

Comment: Thaks for your responses can you please give some hint through code. I will update first my question with code.

Comment: I updated now sorry for late code was too long I shortend it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `posts` to your state

```
this.state = {
    next: "",
    posts : []
    qwerty: []
};
```

for the fetchData method save the state of posts

```
fetchData() {
    return fetch('https://shopconapp.herokuapp.com/api/pagination/')

        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseData) => {
            if (!responseData) {
                navigate("Login");
            } else {
                console.log(responseData);

                let ds = new ListView.DataSource({ rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2 });
                this.setState({
                    nexturl: responseData.next,
                    posts : responseData.results.post ,
                    qwerty: ds.cloneWithRows(responseData.results.post),
                });
            }
        })
}
```

now in `onEndReach` append the new posts to previous posts and make your data source from the state

```
_onEndReached(){

    url = this.state.nexturl;

    return fetch(this.state.nexturl)

        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseData) => {
            if (!responseData) {
                navigate("Login");
            } else {
                console.log(responseData);

                let posts = this.state.posts.concat(responseData.results.post);

                let ds = new ListView.DataSource({ rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2 });
                this.setState({
                    nexturl: responseData.next,
                    posts : posts ,
                    qwerty: ds.cloneWithRows(posts),
                });

            }
        })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ES6 syntax to update the array:

```
let ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
this.setState({
   nexturl: responseData.next,
   qwerty: ds.cloneWithRows([...this.state.qwerty, ...responseData.results.post]),
});
```

Comment: Is anything required to run `ES6 syntax` i updated as u given but it showing me error that `Cannot convert undefined or null to object`

Comment: I updated it in both functions. I think at first `this.state.qwerty` is empty so it showing that error

Comment: Please debug, and get the current state inside on _onEndReached. Now for ES6  syntax there is nothing required to run

Comment: I mean this.state.qwerty and your datasource ds which you are passing to the listview